# Excel VBA Exectution of Private Sub even though if-criteria is not fullfilled

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm using `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` to react to a changes in `Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow)` in each of this cells is a dropdown list which is defined as follow:

```
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim lastcell As Long

lastrow2 = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row
lastcell = Tabelle3.Range("AH1048576").End(xlUp).Row  

For Each Cell In Tabelle3.Range(Tabelle3.Cells(9, 48), Tabelle3.Cells(lastcell, 48))

    If Cell = "" Then

            Dim MyList(2) As String

                MyList(0) = "Relevant"
                MyList(1) = "For Discussion"
                MyList(2) = "Not Relevant"


            With Tabelle3.Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow2).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, Application.International(xlListSeparator))
            End With

    End If

Next
```

Those lines are incorporated into a macro which fills `Tabelle3`with data and all necessary functions, such as the dropdown field.

The `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` is defined as follow:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row

    On Error Resume Next

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "Relevant" Or Target.Value = "For Discussion" Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Cells(Target.Row, "A").Resize(, 57).Copy
        Tabelle14.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Tabelle14.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Tabelle14.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
        Cells(Target.Row, "A").Resize(, 2).Copy
        Tabelle10.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If

'//Delete all duplicate rows
Set Rng = Tabelle10.UsedRange
Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)


End Sub
```

As you can see the first part of the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` 'should' only be executed `If in a dropdown field in Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow) the option 'Relevant' or 'For Discussion' is selected` and the second part `If anything is selceted` , therefore I have used `Target.Value <> ""`. This is principally working fine but one bug occurs.

If I insert the data to `Tabelle3` through the already mentioned macro, it seems the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` is then automatically executed for `row 9 in Tabelle3`and I can find its data in `Tabelle14` and `Tabelle10` as defined.

Does someone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making these changes:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SetTabelle3Validation()

    Const V_LIST = "Relevant,For Discussion,Not Relevant"

    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = Tabelle3
    Dim lr As Long:         lr = ws.Range("AV" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim app As Application: Set app = Application

    Dim fc As Range

    If lr > 9 Then
        Set fc = ws.Range(ws.Cells(9, "AV"), ws.Cells(lr, "AV"))
        fc.Validation.Delete

        fc.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        If fc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
            app.EnableEvents = False
            app.ScreenUpdating = False
            With fc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Validation
              .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                   AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                   Operator:=xlBetween, _
                   Formula1:=Join(Split(V_LIST, ","), app.International(xlListSeparator))
            End With
            app.ScreenUpdating = True
            app.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        fc.AutoFilter
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lr As Long:         lr = Me.Rows.Count
    Dim lrT3 As Long:       lrT3 = Me.Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row
    Dim app As Application: Set app = Application
    Dim inAV As Boolean

    inAV = Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("AV9:AV" & lrT3)) Is Nothing

    With Target
        If .Cells.CountLarge > 1 Or Not inAV Or Len(.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub

        app.EnableEvents = False
        If .Value = "Relevant" Or .Value = "For Discussion" Then
            Me.Cells(.Row, "A").Resize(, 57).Copy
            With Tabelle14.Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            End With
            Tabelle14.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
        End If

        Me.Cells(.Row, "A").Resize(, 2).Copy
        With Tabelle10
            .Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
        End With
        app.CutCopyMode = False
        app.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

---

In `SetTabelle3Validation()`

- Replace `For` loop with `AutoFilter` for speed
- Turn `Application.EnableEvents` Off to stop triggering `Worksheet_Change()` (then back On)

In `Worksheet_Change()`

- Exit the Sub if pasting multiples values, Target is not in col AV, or is empty
- Else (`Target` is in col `AV`, and not empty)

  - Turn `Application.EnableEvents` Off
  - If `Target` value is `"Relevant"` Or `"For Discussion"`, update `Tabelle14`
  - Else (`Target` value is `"Not Relevant"`), update `Tabelle10`
  - Turn `Application.EnableEvents` On

---

Assumptions

- All objects starting with `Tabelle` are the *Code Names* of other sheets
- `Worksheet_Change()` belongs to `Tabelle3`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your perfect solution, it does a great job! :) I did some small adjustments to your `Worksheet_Change()` code to fit my needs 100% (see edit). :)

Comment: One more question occured: I added the `.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)` to `Tabelle14`as well. But somehow the duplicates in `Tabelle14` are not removed. Do you have an idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: @HPM I'm glad it helped :) I found your edit - it was rejected, but I updated my answer with your changes. Except for _On Error Resume Next_. You shouldn't use this line except in rare occasions when you expect errors that cannot be dealt with (and then turn Error handling back on with _On Error GoTo 0_). What errors are you getting? We can handle those as well

Comment: For `.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)` - it has to be qualified properly, like this: `Tabelle14.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)` (duplicates will be removed from column `A`)

Comment: I used the _On Error Resume Next_ because some error occored when I tried to run `Tabelle3.UsedRange.Offset(8).ClearContents` and this line fixed this issue. However, I've just deleted _On Error Resume Next_ and it works now. Even though, I have no clue what happened to be honest. :D

Comment: I tried `Tabelle14.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)` but the duplicates still remain in `Tabelle14`.

Comment: I've found the problem. `Cell A1` is empty therefor I had to change offset the range. `Tabelle14.UsedRange.Offset(3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)` . This line also makes the _On Error Resume Next_ redundant. The only thing I would like to improve is that the `RemoveDuplicates` function removes the older entry in `Tabelle14` not as usually the newer one. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Nice work! About not removing older duplicates the issue is a bit different. You should open a new question, provide a small sample data with _before_ and _after_ so people can see the pattern that you want to keep; but you'll probably need a custom function - `.RemoveDuplicates` is indiscreminent (it removes all dupes, regardless of date or order)

Comment: I just did!  ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531843/use-removeduplicates-function-and-keep-last-entry )
Thanks alot for your support :)