# Use RemoveDuplicates Function And Keep Last Entry

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, find

I'm using following `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` (created with support from paul bica):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lr As Long, lrT3 As Long, inAV As Boolean

lr = Me.Rows.Count
lrT3 = Me.Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row
inAV = Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("AV9:AV" & lrT3)) Is Nothing


With Target

    'Exit Sub if pasting multiples values, Target is not in col AV, or is empty
    If .Cells.CountLarge > 1 Or Not inAV Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If .Value = "Relevant" Or .Value = "For Discussion" Then
        Me.Cells(.Row, "A").Resize(, 57).Copy
        With Tabelle14.Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With

        Me.Cells(.Row, "A").Resize(, 2).Copy
        With Tabelle10
            .Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With


    ElseIf .Value = "Not Relevant" Then
        Me.Cells(.Row, "A").Resize(, 2).Copy
        With Tabelle10
            .Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End With


'//Delete all duplicate rows
Tabelle10.UsedRange.Offset(3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)

Tabelle14.UsedRange.Offset(3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)


End Sub
```

**1. Challenge**

As it can occur that the status is changed from `Relevant` to `For Discussion` or vice versa. There would be temporary two entries in
    `Tabelle14`for this company before the last one is deleted again,
    due to the `Tabelle14.UsedRange.Offset(3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)`. However I would like to keep the last entry and delete the earlier instead, because it contains the updated status. Does someone know how I have to adjust my code to do this or can hint me the right direction?

**2. Challenge**

If `.Value = "Not Relevant"` I want to check `Tabelle14` if the identification code (Tabelle3 column A) can there be found as well and if yes the row should be deleted in `Tabelle14`. 
For example, if in `Tabelle3 Column AV Row 23` the status is set to `Not Relevant`I want the code to prove if the identification number in `Tabelle3 Cell A23` can be found in `Tabelle14 Column A` as well and if the identifaction number is found in e.g. `Tabelle14 Cell A 48` I want to delete the whole row. 
My first thought was to use `FIND` but I haven't figured out so far how to use `FIND` with a variable. Would be happy if someone has a hint for me. :)

Comment: Related to 1: You'll have to write your own function, or sort the table first on a date column, newest to oldest. RemoveDuplicates will always keep the first occurance. 
Related to 2: Here's a hint: You can use `Application.Match` :)

Comment: @RikSportel 1. okay so if I would add a timestamp to each line, showing when exactly the time a row was marked as 'Relevant' or 'For Discussion'. I could use `Autofilter` (last entry on top) and thereafter apply the `RemoveDuplicates` . Do you think that would work out?

Comment: Try it :) not sure if autofilter will do the trick, but for sure the sort method will. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel

Comment: @RikSportel 2. `Application.Match` sounds like a suitable option. But how can I select the value in column A for exactly this row where I've selected 'Not Relevant'?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `RemovePrevious()` sub bellow

It uses `Find` to to look for previous record ID (in column `A`)

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lr As Long, lrT3 As Long, inAV As Boolean

    lr = Me.Rows.Count
    lrT3 = Me.Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row
    inAV = Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("AV9:AV" & lrT3)) Is Nothing

    With Target
        If .Cells.CountLarge > 1 Or Not inAV Then Exit Sub

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If .Value = "Relevant" Or .Value = "For Discussion" Then
            Me.Cells(.Row, "A").Resize(, 57).Copy
            With Tabelle14.Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            End With
            Me.Cells(.Row, "A").Resize(, 2).Copy
            Tabelle10.Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ElseIf .Value = "Not Relevant" Then
            RemovePrevious Me.Cells(.Row, "A")
            Me.Cells(.Row, "A").Resize(, 2).Copy
            With Tabelle10
                .Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
        End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
    Tabelle10.UsedRange.Offset(3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)
    Tabelle14.UsedRange.Offset(3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub RemovePrevious(ByRef itm As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, prev As Variant, cnt As Byte, v As String, r As Long

    Set ws = itm.Parent
    v = itm.Value
    r = itm.Row

    With ws.UsedRange.Columns(itm.Column)

        Set prev = .Find(What:=v, After:=ws.Cells(9, itm.Column), LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

        If Not prev Is Nothing Then
            While Not prev Is Nothing And prev.Row = r
                If Not prev Is Nothing And prev.Row = r Then Set prev = .FindNext(v)
            Wend
        End If

    End With

    If Not prev Is Nothing Then If prev.Row <> r Then prev.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do I have to place the `RemovePrevious()` sub? Beneath the `Worksheet_Change` sub? If I try so, it seems that it doesn't work

Comment: _it doesn't work_ - you mean it doesn't remove the previous value? You can place it in any module (including under `Worksheet_Change()`), and it will use the parent of the cell used as parameter. Can you step through it using `F8` and verify `ws` name, `itm` value, and `prev` value? (I tested it)

Comment: sorry for the unclear comment. I tried going through the code by using `F8` but unfortunately I'm not able to. Do have an idea what is going wrong here? Thanks a lot for your help again :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I’m still not sure what you mean by _not able to_: is the code not executing at all? If that’s the case you may have the events disabled. You can turn them back on running this Sub (with `F5`): **`Sub EE(): Application.EnableEvents = True: End Sub`**